# How to get unicode value of a Bengali character in php

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding, special-characters

I swear this is not duplicate , because I did not my find my answer from those questions and answers at all.

I am working a project where I should know unicode values of **Bengali characters**.A bengali character '**ক**' has unicode value of '**0x0995**'.

I found many function on net , but unfortunately they are not working with Bengali language.May be because Bengali is multi byte language.

Is there any function in php(user-defined or built-in) , like

**somefunction(ক);**

and it will provide the value **0995**.

**[please test your code for character ক whether it provide hex 0995 or equivalent before you suggest me,]**

Thank you.

Comment: `echo json_encode('ক');`

Comment: What do you mean by multi-byte language? Then are there languages that single-byte? If so, how on earth would you use a single-byte language?

Comment: @roullie : thanks it is working ...but "\u0995"  how to remove these double quotation and \u .

Comment: @Shadowfax Maybe english is single byte language, Because it fits in ASCII. I said multi byte because I found a function on net,which provide me an error saying about it..Nothing serious. Do you have any perticular answer for my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP<7, This version of `uniord` deals correctly with characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane:

```
function uniord($s) {
    return unpack('V', iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4LE', $s))[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 7, you can use the builtin class [IntlChar](http://php.net/intlchar) from intl extension:

```
var_dump(IntlChar::chr('ক')); # => int(2453)
```

Just to add a dechex to convert from decimal to hexa or, for a custom format, (s)printf (eg: `U+%08X`).

Answer (score 0):

```
               function uniord($u) {
                    $k = mb_convert_encoding($u, 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8');
                    $k1 = ord(substr($k, 0, 1));
                    $k2 = ord(substr($k, 1, 1));
                    return $k2 * 256 + $k1;
                }
                echo uniord('ক');
```